# How to call function in class to function another class in php?

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to call a funtion in class to function another class
with example this code:

```
class test1{
    public function a(){
        echo "Test";
    }
}

class test2
{
    public function b()
    {
        $obj = new test1(); 
        $obj->a();  
    }
}
```

what is correct way??

Comment: And what is the question / problem now?

Comment: extend your parent class to the child class. LOL

Comment: my problem is:call function a in class test2!

Comment: ^@FatemehNamkhah Ah, so my guess was right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm trying to call a funtion in class to function another class with example this code:*

I assume you are not being able to *call* it?

```
<?php

class test1{
    public function a(){
        echo "Test";
    }

}
class test2
{
    public function b()
    {
        $obj = new test1(); 
        $obj->a();  
    }

}

    $t2 = new test2;
    $t2->b();
?>
```

Comment: my problem is:call function a in class test2

Comment: @FatemehNamkhah isn't that what's already happening? you _obviously_ got to call the `function b()` at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
class test1{
    public function a(){
        echo "Test";
    }
}

class test2
{
    public function b()
    {
        $obj = new test1(); 
        $obj->a();  
    }
}

$myTest2 = new test2();
$myTest2->b();
```

Comment: my problem is:call function a in class test2

Comment: in your posted code works fine without changes.

Comment: Yes, work, but you need to instance test2 before and call test2->b() function.

Try now the code i published

Comment: @FatemehNamkhah Your code works fine: https://eval.in/440237